# ActionBarSherlock produces a java.lang.nullexception on my xml layout files

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using eclipse to develop my android app. Normally, when editing the xml layout files, a graphical layout is presented. However when I include the ActionBarSherlock as a library, I get a Java.Lang.NullPointerException when I go to the graphical editor.

When I take the ActionBarSherlock away, I am able to get my normal editor back. I thought it was a fault with my themes, but I have followed what was told on the ActionBarSherlock website.

Comment: Please post the relevant code so we can see what is happening. Otherwise there is a great [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GJ6yY1lNNY&feature=player_embedded) from ActionBar Sherlock to walk you through using ABS.

Comment: Just wanted to say this reminds me of a custom view error. If you didn't inherit ALL constructors of View in your class (CustomView(Context), CustomView(Context, AttrSet), CustomView(Context, AttrSet, int)) the editor and devices throw NullPointerException. I am not acknowledged enough about ABS so that's all I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea why ActionBarSherlock is doing this, and even though the graphical editor displays the NULL exception, the code when deployed runs fine. I suspect that it is a problem with the theme, even though it was setup exactly as was described on the ABS site.